# How to extend Relationship class in neo4django

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4django

I've seen that relationship properties are not yet implemented in neo4django. The workaround exposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092066/neo4django-relationship-properties) is to have a new node type for each relationship with a property.

I can't afford too much calculations so I don't want to use this technique. While reading the [source code](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/blob/master/neo4django/db/models/relationships.py) I've seen, as the docstring of the `Relationship` class, this : `"""Extend to add properties to relationships."""`

My question is, how to do that ? Where to start to add at least one property ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe raise an issue in the project and get help from the creators?

Answer (score 3):

Despite the docstring, this is still an [open issue](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues/1)- the project's oldest, actually. There might be a way for you to pull it off by extending `Relationship` and `BoundRelationship`, but it won't be easy until I'm able to close that issue.

I would argue that this issue probably won't be a bottleneck using the project, since you can just give Neo4j more memory for the node store than the relationship store to account for it. YMMV of course.

I know it feels like a hack, though. If you really need custom relationship properties, the shortest path might be dropping down to the REST client level. To create relationships with properties, you could do something like

```
class Person(NodeModel):
  name = StringProperty()
  friends = Relationship('self', rel_type='friends_with')

pete = Person.objects.create(name='Pete')
dave = Person.objects.create(name='Dave')

# from the neo4j-rest-client [docs][2]
pete.node.relationships.create("friends_with", dave.node, since=123456789, introduced_at="Christmas party")
```

WDYT?

Comment: Thanks @Matt, is it possible to do that from inside the class ? Like `self.node.relationships.create(...)`

Comment: Absolutely. You could also do this in a Manager. If you need more power or want some custom relationship filtering to go along with your properties, you could try something like https://gist.github.com/bramd/5460611#file-models-py-L72 . (NB - in that example he's using Cypher, and the `node` variable would be better named `instance` to mark it as a model instance, not a REST client node object)

Comment: If you share some domain details or a motivating example, I'd be happy to provide a more tailored gist :)